# In Jetbrains-Webstorm, how do I configure it so all my nodejs files have global and 10.3 scope?

Tags: webstorm

The editor keeps bugging me with warnings that he doesn't understand what "require" means as well as module.exports and I have to manually add to use 10.3 and globals for each js in my project, with is a huge bother.

How can I set it to default to this?

Comment: Did you try [configuring the scope here](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/5949/20130415151716.png)?

Comment: this be the solution, thanks! I've yet to use this editor before, used to like netbeans but webstorm is much smarter, from what I can tell.